# How would I convert this Data to Struct Model from BLE Device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to read some data from a BLE device,

The output LOG is <0e000100 00006043 75591800 00000024 00000200 00006c44 75591800 0000001e 00000300 00003745 75591800 0000001e 00000400 0000d238 75591800 00000024 00000500 0000c139 75591800 0000001e 00000600 00001c3b 75591800 0000001e 00000700 0000d93b 75591800 0000001d 00000800 0000af3e 75590000 00000000 00000900 0000d03e 75591800 0000001e 00000a00 00002041 75591800 0000001e 00000b00 00000642 75591800 0000001e 00000c00 0000>

It should read me out something like in this structure, an array inside the struct that has some items structs in that array

```
typedef struct ItemStruct {
    uint16_t               sessionID;
    uint16_t               sessionType;
    uint32_t               startTime;
    uint32_t               duration;
    uint32_t               storageSize;
} ItemStruct;

typedef struct MyStruct {
    uint16_t itemsCount;
    ItemStruct items[14];
} MyStruct
```

I dont know whats wrong in this, It is not giving me expected values, It looks like they give me pointers not the values for the array object. It is an objective C code.

```
MyStruct sample;

[sampleData getBytes:&sample length:sizeof(sample)];
```

All I know is It is using littleEndian Byte Order.

Here is my description log, printed:

```
(MyStruct) sample = {
  itemsCount = 14
  items = {
    [0] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 17248, startTime = 1595765, duration = 603979776, storageSize = 131072)
    [1] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 17516, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 196608)
    [2] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 17719, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 262144)
    [3] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 14546, startTime = 1595765, duration = 603979776, storageSize = 327680)
    [4] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 14785, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 393216)
    [5] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 15132, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 458752)
    [6] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 15321, startTime = 1595765, duration = 486539264, storageSize = 524288)
    [7] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 16047, startTime = 22901, duration = 0, storageSize = 589824)
    [8] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 16080, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 655360)
    [9] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 16672, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 720896)
    [10] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 16902, startTime = 1595765, duration = 503316480, storageSize = 786432)
    [11] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 0, startTime = 76128384, duration = 1, storageSize = 96502448)
    [12] = (sessionID = 0, sessionType = 0, startTime = 76149328, duration = 1, storageSize = 76149368)
    [13] = (sessionID = 1, sessionType = 0, startTime = 13, duration = 0, storageSize = 90673961)
  }
}
```

But the expected ones are Eg: In the array, Object at index 0 should be

> [0] = (sessionID = 1, sessionType = 3, startTime = -epoch secs gives
>   some date in 2017-, duration = -secs-, storageSize = -some storage
>   size-)

However the first value of itemsCount = 14 is the right one because the devices has 14 sessions in it. And I wonder how it could possibly map that part right.

Comment: You say your data is little-endian but you're using `CFSwapInt16BigToHost` which is what you would use if your data is big-endian.

Comment: What's the result you are supposed to get? It can help you to debug.

Comment: Expect result should be like,  { itemCount = 14, items[IntemsStruc] = <Array objects>} and in the array objects the index one should have the struct object  ItemStruct: { sessionID = 1, sessionType = <Some number>, startTime = <Some Epoch secs of 2017 calender date>. duration = <secs>, storage = <some  size> }

Comment: @dan I just gave a try if that could help me , but no luck,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

`sample.items = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(sample.items);`

In your example, sample.items is a pointer; it makes no sense to swap it as a 32-bit integer. I don't think this would compile, and if the compiler did somehow allow it, it would certainly result in random values getting logged for your items, since the array pointer would be pointing to some random chunk of memory. What you want to do is iterate through sample.items instead, swapping each individual ItemStruct field for each item.

With that said, when eyeballing it, the output you're seeing seems to match the data at the top. Is it possible your method is being given corrupt data?

EDIT: Here's what's going on.

The 'items' pointer in MyStruct is not aligned to a four-byte boundary, which is causing the compiler to add some padding. You can see this if you fill out a struct yourself and then log its bytes:

```
MyStruct sample;

sample.itemsCount = 14;

sample.items[0].sessionID = 1;
sample.items[0].sessionType = 2;
sample.items[0].startTime = 3;
sample.items[0].duration = 4;
sample.items[0].storageSize = 5;

NSLog(@"%@", [NSData dataWithBytes:&sample length:sizeof(sample)]);
```

You get:

`<0e000000 01000200 03000000 04000000 05000000 (...)`

As you can see, there are two bytes of padding after 0e00. This means the two bytes immediately after 0e00 are being skipped, and everything after it gets put two bytes earlier in the struct than where they should be.

Here's my recommendation: Instead of just copying the bytes to the struct, which is prone to problems like this, just do the following instead:

1. Grab the first two bytes of the data, run them through CFSwapInt16LittleToHost, and set itemsCount.
2. Loop from 0 to itemsCount, and for each one, fill out the fields of the ItemStruct by grabbing either the next 2 or 4 bytes, run them through CFSwapInt(16|32)LittleToHost, and fill in the individual fields of items[i].

You have to loop through it anyway to swap all the fields anyway, so it's not that much of an added hassle.

Comment: I agree, That line I have removed, I just gave a try, if that helps to understand if they are littleEndian or BigEndian, But I got it confirmed from the chipset guy that its actually littleEndian Byte Order

Comment: Ah, I see what's causing your problem. One moment while I edit the answer.

Comment: Sure, Take your time, But Some sample code would help at this point of time ;)

Comment: You can do `typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) MyStruct {` to prevent the compiler from padding it.  He shouldn't actually have to do any endianness-swapping since iOS is little endian.

Comment: In the old PowerPC days, I used to assume the Mac would always be big-endian, and not swap anything when reading big-endian data. I learned my lesson at some point. ;-) Nowadays, I recommend explicitly specifying the endianness of data you're reading in. Because with Apple, you never know what they might do in the future.

Comment: Also: If he ends up porting this to Swift at some point, it'll be better for the structs to be built explicitly, since I don't think Swift has any guarantees about the internal layout of its structs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the binary representation of the data.

In your class that holds the structure, implement a "description" method that you can use to print,
NSLog your data.

e.g..

```
- (NSString *)description {
     NSString *descriptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SessionID: %@\n SessionType: %@", your_reference, your_reference];
     return descriptionString;
}
```

Then when you receive the data just cast it to the correct type and call description on it.